# Bash how to append new line at the start of a list in yaml file?

Tags: bash, unix, yaml

I would like to append a new line to the start of a list in a yaml config file, using a bash script.

The config file has several lines... the script has to locate the specific line under `-changelog/changelog.md` and insert a new line at said location when it runs.

```yaml
  - Changelog:
    - changelog/changelog.md
    - Iteration 1.3: changelog/page3.md
    - Iteration 1.2: changelog/page2.md
    - Iteration 1.1: changelog/page1.md
```

And so forth:

```yaml
  - Changelog:
    - changelog/changelog.md
    - Iteration X: changelog/pageX.md #new append via bash!
    - Iteration 1.3: changelog/page3.md
    - Iteration 1.2: changelog/page2.md
    - Iteration 1.1: changelog/page1.md
```

Not sure how to go about this.

Comment: Is there a specific pattern in the line that you want to add after? Use `sed` to match that line, and use its `a` command to add a line.

Comment: The line should closely replicate the same structure as previous lines, so including Iteration number and page number.

Comment: That doesn't answer the question. How do you know which line should get the new line added after it? What's the pattern in that line?

Answer (score 1):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed '\~changelog/changelog.md~{p;s~[[:alpha:]].*~Iteration X: changelog/pageX.md~}' input_file
 - Changelog:
    - changelog/changelog.md
    - Iteration X: changelog/pageX.md
    - Iteration 1.3: changelog/page3.md
    - Iteration 1.2: changelog/page2.md
    - Iteration 1.1: changelog/page1.md
```